# Show android splash screen preserving aspect ratio and cropping sides

Tags: android, xml, imageview, splash-screen

I'd like to show a splash screen right after the app starts, and I want it to preserve its original aspect ratio, while fitting the screen as best as possible, cropping the sides. Let me make an example in numbers. Let's say the splash screen image is 2048x1536 (4x3 ratio). When it shows on a device with 1280x800 screen (16x10), it should scale down to 1280x960 and crop 80px on top and botton.

My SplashScreenActivity looks like this:

```java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

styles.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/splash</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I figured out that ImageView with android:scaleType="centerCrop" might do the trick. But if layout/splash.xml is done like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/splash_bg_portrait" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The app just crashes on start. Is it totally impossible to use ImageView like this or some parameter is wrong?

Also let me note that I don't use setContentView(R.layout.splash) and don't delay the splash activity intentionally, because the purpose of this splash screen is not to add waiting time for the player, but to give the player something to look at, instead of a blank screen, while application is starting.

**UPD.**
Logcat:

```
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager: Token{423c44b8 ActivityRecord{4225d620 u0 com.myapp.jq.google/com.myapp.jq.SplashActivity t15}} failed creating starting window
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f03002d
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3109)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3152)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1718)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:1850)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7825)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag LinearLayout
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2148)
05-27 12:07:42.949   654   673 W WindowManager:     ... 9 more
```

From this it seems like LinearLayout (or any other layout) cannot be used for android:windowBackground.
layer-list in splash.xml works fine:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
      <bitmap
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/splash_bg_portrait"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But unfortunately layer-list doesn't support ImageView, and bitmap neither supports android:scaleType nor has similar functionality.

Comment: Not sure if you can use a layout as windowBackground, its usually a color or drawable resource. anyway post your logcat please.

Comment: Did you tried to place your image directly in android:windowBackground. I think you need to place an image resource for this attribute and not a layout

Comment: If image is placed directly in android:windowBackground

<item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/splashtest</item>

it will be just stretched. Also there are actually two splash screens, for portrait and for landscape modes, layout/splash.xml and layout-land/splash.xml, automatically chosen by the system.